# How to make ImageView draggable from left to right

Tags: android, imageview

I am using an ImageView which covers the full screen of device as like as below :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#1A1A1A"
```

>

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="1000dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

</HorizontalScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_top"
    android:padding="15dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back_arrow"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_header_wallpaper_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cityscape in a dark, cold abyss of light and fire"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_back"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/white_color"
    android:visibility="visible" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_bottom">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_set_wallpaper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/download_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_favourite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/favorites"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I have downloaded the image of size approx 20 Mb from image url and set the image in imageview. Problem is that the width of image is large as compare to the device width. When I applied or set the same image in Image view, it squeeze in size and set in full screen view. What I want that image should not be squeezed. Image view should be draggable from left and right only. Height should be fixed as per device.

How can we make an Image view Draggable ?

Answer (score 0):

This layout will allow to scroll the image :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:src="@drawable/bigimage" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tested it and it works nice for me, your problem must be elsewhere . The other answers give you the same or similar solution ...

Comment: This is my XML file in which I have applied your solution . Please let me know where I am wrong ?

Comment: Your layout is fully wrong the only one root element (for example a Relative Layout) must contain all the elements inside. If you add more views or nested layouts all must be inside the unique root element

Comment: I recommend you first play with a basic layout to understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

```
<HorizontalScrollView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ScrollView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

This will help.